# The even (resp. odd) subsequence of $z_n = f(z_{n-1})$ is constant iff $z_0$ (resp. $z_1$) is a fixed point of $f\{f(z)\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm given a function, $f(z)=z_n=\frac{1}{2}z_{n-1}^2+1$.

I'm trying to prove the following:

(1) The even subsequence $(z_{2m}) = (z_0, z_2, z_4, \dots)$ is constant $\iff z_0$ is a fixed point of $h : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, h(z)=f\{f(z)\}$;

(2) The odd subsequence $(z_{2m+1}) = (z_1, z_3, z_5, \dots)$ is constant $\iff z_1$ is a fixed point of $h : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, h(z)=f\{f(z)\}$.

About proving the $\impliedby$ direction:

(1) If $z_0$ is a fixed point of $h$, then $z_0=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{2}z_0^2-1]^2-1 \implies z_0=1 \pm i, -1 \pm i\sqrt5 $, but then how do I show that this sequence is constant?

Comment: The sequence is given by $z_{n+1} = f(z_n)$.

Comment: Sorry; yes- edited now.

Comment: That was meant as a hint to prove the $\Longleftarrow$ direction.

Comment: ah... And what about the converse direction; how would I go about proving that?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the particular function $f$, it works for any function $X \to X$.

Note that $f(z_{n-1}) = z_n$, so $h(z_{n-2}) = f(f(z_{n-2})) = f(z_{n-1}) = z_n$.

Suppose $z_0$ is a fixed point of $h$. We will show by induction that $z_{2m} = z_0$ for every $m$. The base case, $m = 1$, holds because $z_0 = h(z_0) = z_2$. Now suppose $z_{2(k-1)} = z_0$, then $z_{2k} = h(z_{2(k-1)}) = h(z_0) = z_0$. Therefore, $z_{2m} = z_0$ for every $m$; that is, the subsequence $(z_{2m})$ is constant.

The argument for the subsequence $(z_{2m+1})$ is analogous.